# Mips programming jump problems

Tags: windows, assembly, mips

Supposed to count number of R, I, and J instructions in the code starting from the first line in main.  I have updated the code to all suggestions but results do not seem correct still.  :(

EDIT: added those syntax changes, the variables seem to be working better, but the loop doesn't seem to be properly running through itself at all.  Any noticeable problems anyone sees?

EDIT2: How do i change the loop to make $t1 rotate through 1 instruction set at a time? THAT is my key problem right now other than the silly syntax from a new mips user.

EDIT3: I have updated the code to all suggestions but results do not seem correct still.  :(

```mips
.text    
Main:    
la $t1, 0x400000    
li $t5, 0    
li $t3, 2    
li $t4, 3    
li $t2, 0    
la $s0, 0x400000 

loop:    
lw $t1, 0($s0)    
addi $s0, 4    
addi $t5, 1     
beq $t5, 20 exit    
srl $s4, $t1, 26    
beq $s4, $t2 R    
beq $s4, $t3 J    
beq $s4, $t4 J    
addi $s3, 1    
j loop    

R:
addi $s1, 1    
j loop      

J:    
addi $s2, 1    
j loop     

exit:    
sw $s1, RType    
sw $s2, JType    
sw $s3, IType    
jr $ra
```

Comment: Still need help for the code to actually count correctly

Answer (score 1):

I see a set of problems:

1) Initialize the registers (don't assume register initial value is zero). For example, `addi $t5, 1` requieres a previous `add $t5, $zero, $zero` (or `li` to the value you want).

2) the beq jump instruction requires two registers. For example, you have to change `beq $s4, 3 J` by:

```
li $t6, 3
beq $s4, $t6, J
```

Comment: How do i change the loop to make $t1 rotate through 1 instruction set at a time in order? THAT is my key problem right now other than the silly syntax from a new mips user.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Miguel's points I'd like to add that you're using the instruction set in a strange manner. Perhaps your assembler is capable of figuring out what you meant, but it's still makes the code confusing to read.

```
lw $t3, 2
lw $t4, 3
```

These should be `li`. The `lw` instruction is used for loading words from memory.

---

```
la $t0, 4($t1)
```

This should be `lw`, and unless you only want to check the instructions starting from address 0x400004 you should drop the offset.

I also can't seem to find anywhere where you increment `$t1`, so you'll be using the same address for every iteration of the loop.

Comment: How do i change the loop to make $t1 rotate through 1 instruction set at a time?  THAT is my key problem right now other than the silly syntax from a new mips user.